# change URL with zend

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I have a module in zend framework that I can acces with this URl : `www.example.com/questionnaire/`

I would like to change the `questionnaire` in the URl to `questionnaire-test` .

This is the code I have extracted from the `Bootsrap.php` file but can't work out what I need to change.

```
if(!in_array('backoffice', $layout) && (in_array('questionnaire', $layout))){

    $langRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':lang/',
         array(
            'lang' => 'fr',
         )
    );

    $defaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':controller/:action',
        array(
            'module'=>'questionnaire',
        'controller'=>'index',
        'action'=>'index'
        )
    );


    $defaultRoute = $langRoute->chain($defaultRoute);

    $router->addRoute('langRoute', $langRoute);
    $router->addRoute('defaultRoute', $defaultRoute);
    /*---------------------------------*/
    $router->addRoute('home',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            '([a-z]{2})/',
        array(
            'module'=>'questionnaire',
        'controller'=>'index',
        'action'=>'index'
            ),
        array(
            1 => 'lang',
        ),
        '%s/'
    )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definition seems to be the home route `www.example.com/en/` and not `www.example.com/en/questionnaire/`.
The right definition should be the following if your're looking for `www.example.com/en/questionnaire-test/`:

```
$router->addRoute('questionnaire',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '([a-z]{2})/questionnaire-test',
        array(
            'module'=>'questionnaire',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
        ),
        array(
            1 => 'lang',
        ),
       '%s/questionnaire-test'
    )
);
```

Comment: I updated my question with more code you might be right for the home route. With the code you provide I manage to acces the module with `www.example/questionnaire/questionnaire-test` but I can't change the first occurence of "questionnaire"

Comment: Are you sure these are the only route definitions? There could be other definitions in a controller plugin for example..

Answer (score 0):

Standard router `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` uses by default the route that will match by name :module/:controller/:action request. You can disable this by calling

```
$router->removeDefaultRoutes();
```

That should make the router work only based on the routes you define. Then you should be able to reach the module like this:

```
$router->addRoute(new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('questionnaire-test/:controller/:action', array(
    'module' => 'questionnaire',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index')));
```